# PWA limitar el peso de las fotos

Tags: html5, pwa

En la aplicación que estoy desarrollando, el usuario debe tomar una foto con la cámara de su celular, el problema es que hoy casi todos los usuarios en sus cámaras las tienen configuradas a máxima resolución generando fotos muy pesadas. 
Como puedo hacer que mi aplicación web al abrir la cámara limite a una resolución especifica la foto. la idea es no tener que procesar la foto en el servidor para bajar el peso, si no que llegue lista desde el lado del cliente a mi servidor.
Espero se entienda la pregunta.

```html
<form id="enviar" class="form" action="./controlers/crear-obsconducta.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                    
<input name="quien" id="quien" placeholder="Realizada por:" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                                                               
                                                               
<label for="" class="col-form-label">Descripcion de la situacion / incluir la correccion</label>
                                                        
<textarea name="descripcion" id="descripcion" class="form-control" required></textarea>

<div class="">Evidencia visual(foto)</label><input name="img[]" id="foto" type="file" class="form-control-file" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg" required = "required"> 
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                  
</form>
```

```html
<!--en el lado del servidor tomo la imagen la proceso -->

<?php
$new_name= time();
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][0], 'img.jpg');
$imagenresize= new ResizeImage('img.jpg');
$imagenresize->resizeTo(600,600,'exact');
$imagenresize->saveImage('../fotosObs/Ocond-'.$new_name.'.jpg');

$url = "../fotosObs/Ocond-".$new_name.".jpg";
unlink('img.jpg');

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

crea dos elementos en tu html, aqui podras ver la salida
y ya solo lo ajustas el guardado del elemento salida:

```
<input type="button" value="Resize Image"  onclick="ResizeImage()"/> 
<img src="" id="output">
```

agrega el siguiente script,

```
  function ResizeImage() {
       //valor de foto
    var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('foto').files;
    var file = filesToUpload[0];

    // crea una copia
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    // Create a file reader
    var reader = new FileReader();
    //
    reader.onload = function(e) {
            img.src = e.target.result;

            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            var MAX_WIDTH = 600;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;

            if (width > height) {
                if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                    width = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            } else {
                if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

            var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.getElementById('output').src = dataurl;
        }
        // 
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: Funciono muy bien, pero ahora tengo otro problema, cuando las imagenes son muy pesadas no funciona la transformación, no se cual sera el error o como corregirlo @Miguel Zarate